# PrimeCheck 8086 Assembly Bug

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I wrote a 8086 Assembly program which does the following thing:

1. Gets Input From User
2. Convert it to integer
3. Check if it is prime

The problem is with step 3 and it has a bug.
It says 9 is a prime and is in an infinite loop when input is 2.
I checked and there is no problem with input.
I don't know what the problem is.

Code:

```
    MOV AL,NUM
    MOV BL,02H      ; The Dividing starts from 2, Hence BH is compare to 02H
    MOV DX,0000H    ; To avoid Divide overflow error
    MOV AH,00H      ; To avoid Divide overflow error
```

Loop to check for Prime No

```
L1:
    DIV BL
    CMP AH,00H      ; Remainder is compared with 00H (AH)
    JNE NEXT
    INC BH          ; BH is incremented if the Number is divisible by current value of BL
NEXT:
    CMP BH,02H      ; If BH > 02H, There is no need to proceed, It is not a Prime
    JE FALSE        ; The no is not a Prime No
    INC BL          ; Increment BL
    MOV AX,0000H    ; To avoid Divide overflow error
    MOV DX,0000H    ; To avoid Divide overflow error
    MOV AL,NUM      ; Move the Default no to AL
    CMP BL,NUM      ; Run the loop until BL matches Number. I.e, Run loop x no of times, where x is the Number given
    JNE L1          ; Jump to check again with incremented value of BL
```

Print Results:

```
    ;To display The given no is a Prime No
TRUE:
    LEA DX,MSG
    MOV AH,09H      ; Used to print a string
    INT 21H
    JMP EXIT

    ;To display The given no is not a Prime No
FALSE:    
    LEA DX,NMSG
    MOV AH,09H      ; Used to print a string
    INT 21H
```

I think it only happens for one digit numbers.

Comment: You don't appear to initialize `BH`.

Comment: It is set to zero at the beginning. no problem there

Comment: Please post your actual code, then.

Comment: All numbers `n <= 3` are prime, special case that so you can skip even divisors inside your loop.  See also [Checking if a number is prime in NASM Win64 Assembly](//codereview.stackexchange.com/q/204902)/ for a more efficient prime-checking loop which checks the quotient against divisor to stop at about `sqrt(n)` instead of uselessly going all the way up to `n-1`.  Porting the algorithm to x86-16 for 8-bit integers should be simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CMP BH,02H
> JE FALSE
> ;
> CMP BL,NUM
> JNE L1
> ```

### This is your problem.

If you don't allow dividing the number by itself then your *false* criterion should become `CMP BH, 1`.
If you do allow dividing the number by itself (but why should you?) checking for `BH=2` is correct.

---

The number is not prime as soon as you get a zero remainder from division by 2 to N-1.
e.g. for the number 9, you divide by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
The zero remainder already happens at 3 and thus 'not prime'

```
 MOV  BL, 2
L1:
 XOR  AX, AX
 MOV  AL, NUM
 DIV  BL
 TEST AH, AH
 JZ   FALSE
 INC  BL
 CMP  BL, NUM
 JB   L1
```

---

> is in an infinite loop when input is 2.

You must single out that case. You can't iterate from 2 to N-1 for the number 2.
The smallest number you can safely process is 3 (2 to 2).

The reason why your code crashes on this is because you've used `JNE L1`. See in my snippet how I've used `JB L1`?